# Hidden printer job queue

Tags: printing

My Brother-MFC-J4625DW is not printing from Ubuntu 16.04 anymore (but from Windows 10). Whatever I do, it increases the job number, but never prints anything. And it never forgets the last job numer.

1. I print a test page as **job number 555**, nothing happens.
2. I delete the printer from the system settings.
3. I set back the printer to factory settings.
4. When I reinstall via USB, LAN or WLAn and print a test page, it queues as **job numer 556**. 
   (Note: Cups is never showing a printer on http://localhost:631.)

Where is that mysterious backend job queue located and how to kill it???
Regards Tobias

Comment: `service cups status`, `ps -fu lp` will help

Comment: This is the output:
ps -fu lp
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
lp        5866  5854  0 08:58 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
lp       25993  5854  0 21:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://